# How can the screen be updated periodically for yahoo weather/simple pie?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, simplepie, yahoo-weather-api

I am using yahoo weather feed and simplepie to get weather for my digital display. Since it is a website run on a screen, I can't refresh the browser all the time manually.

I am just wondering is there anything eg jquery or php doc can help me update the weather information periodically as the weather changes?? If so would you be able to give me some directions on how to implement? your help is greatly appreciated.

Here is some of my code just in case it is useful

```
<div id="weather">
        <div id="title">
                <ul>
                    <!--<li> Outside Temp </li>-->
                    <li> Today </li>
                    <li> Tomorrow </li>

                </ul>
        </div> <!--title-->

        <div id="forecast">

        <div id="images">
            <ul>
                <?php foreach ($weather->get_forecasts() as $forecast): ?>

                <li><img src="<?php echo $forecast->get_image(); ?>" alt="Weather" /></li>

                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
         </div> <!--images-->

        <div id="degrees">
            <ul>
                <?php foreach ($weather->get_forecasts() as $forecast): ?>

                <li><?php echo $forecast->get_low(); ?>&deg; &nbsp; <?php echo $forecast->get_high(); ?>&deg; </li>

                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
            </div><!--degrees-->

    </div> <!--forecast-->
<!--</div> <!--second-->
```

Some header part info:

```
<php

require_once('simplepie/simplepie.inc');
require_once('simplepie/simplepie_yahoo_weather.inc');

$feed = new SimplePie();

$feed->set_feed_url('http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=1234567&u=c'); 

$feed->set_item_class('SimplePie_Item_YWeather');

$feed->init();

$weather = $feed->get_item(0);

?>
```

Thank you very much!

S:)

Comment: use a ajax request on some interval of time using setInterval

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're not already using JavaScript, a really simple way for you to periodically refresh the page might be to use the [meta refresh tag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh). Although deprecated, it might be a quick way for you to get dynamic pages. Simply add the tag to the `<head>` of the page:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5"> <!--Refresh the page every 5 seconds-->
```

However, you might want to consider using ajax to load your content into the page instead. This might not be the best possible approach to this but here's some quick and dirty code.

In the main page, you could use jQuery [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) to periodically hit the URL for your PHP script and load the content into a `div` for display:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            setTimeout(loadWeather, 5000); //using setTimeout instead of a setInterval to avoid having multiple queries queue up when the first one fails to return within the timeout period
        });

        function loadWeather(){
            $('#weather').load('weather.php);
            setTimeout(loadWeather, 5000);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="weather" />
</body>
</html>
```

where `weather.php` might look something like this:

```
<div id="weather">
        <div id="title">
                <ul>
                    <!--<li> Outside Temp </li>-->
                    <li> Today </li>
                    <li> Tomorrow </li>

                </ul>
        </div> <!--title-->

        <div id="forecast">

        <div id="images">
            <ul>
                <?php foreach ($weather->get_forecasts() as $forecast): ?>

                <li><img src="<?php echo $forecast->get_image(); ?>" alt="Weather" /></li>

                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
         </div> <!--images-->

        <div id="degrees">
            <ul>
                <?php foreach ($weather->get_forecasts() as $forecast): ?>

                <li><?php echo $forecast->get_low(); ?>&deg; &nbsp; <?php echo $forecast->get_high(); ?>&deg; </li>

                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
            </div><!--degrees-->

    </div> <!--forecast-->
<!--</div> <!--second-->
```

Comment: Hi coding, can you please give me some examples/code to work on? I have used javascript for other parts of the display, I tried some jquery refresh but it seemed to stop some parts of my site work. Any help is appreciated. Thanks, S:)

Comment: @SamIAm Please see my updated answer for one possible (simplistic) solution.

Comment: Hi coding, thanks very much for your reply, I really appreciate. I was just writing what I've found and here you are faster than me. I've found an ajax and javascript way, here is the code <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $("#weather").load("weather.php");
   var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
      $("#weather").load('weather.php?randval='+ Math.random());
   }, 9000);
   $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
});
</script> Do you think it will work the same way as your suggestion? Which way is better? Thank you very much! S:)

Comment: @SamIAm As you'll notice, both your script and mine essentially are the same in that they use jQuery's `load()` method to make the ajax request to the weather PHP script and then set the div contents to the response. There are minor improvements in your script which might be required such as disabling caching and adding a unique value to the request URL query string in order to force the browser NOT to cache the request.

Comment: The biggest difference would be the use of `setInterval` vs `setTimeout`. As I've pointed out in my answer, `setInterval` *could* potentially cause multiple requests to queue up - consider where the weather PHP script takes more than 9 seconds to respond. In such a case, a second request to the weather script would fire before the first one ever returns. `setInterval` will fire every 9 seconds, irrespective of whether you've completed your earlier request or not. My code attempts to avoid this by explicitly using `setTimeout` each time the weather is fetched.

Comment: You can use either one of these - it's really up to you as long as you make an informed decision by knowing what you're doing and what the alternatives are.

Comment: Thanks very much for your detailed explanation! I'm new to this, and your answers have certainly helped me. I will use your suggestion now. I really appreciate your help. Hope you have a great week! Thanks! S:)

Comment: Hi Coding, sorry to bother you again, I've found one little problem, the weather feed doesn't update in IE, what shall I do with your code to make it work in IE9? Thank you very much.

Comment: Do I just put Can I just put $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); in the end? Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm not sure what problem you might be facing with IE9 - perhaps you could post a new question with a stripped down working example that reproduces the problem? Also, you should set cache to false *before* you make any ajax requests so you should set that up first.

Comment: Thanks very much for helping me, I've put $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); in the end, it is doing the job. Thanks again, really appreciate! S:)